# Why did RVM break my MANPATH on mac osx?

Tags: macos, rvm, manpage

Ever since installing RVM, my manpages are broken.  Current versions of man don't use the MANPATH variable, so why is it being set to .rvm/man  and why isn't there a full catalog of manpages inside that folder?

Comment: What makes you think that `man` doesn't use MANPATH?  If you do `man man` on your Mac, you can see that it definitely *is* used.

Comment: If you don't specify -M but set the MANPATH environment variable, the value of that variable is the list of the directories that man searches.

Since OSX 10.2 MANPATH is not generally set, and instead mapages are found based on a canonical directory structure.  By setting MANPATH, RVM was disrupting this behavior.

Comment: So what you mean to say is that OSX doesn't *set* MANPATH.  That's a very different thing that saying that `man` doesn't *use* MANPATH.  Obviously it uses it, or this bug in rvm wouldn't affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in the script ~/.rvm/scripts/initialize there is a little block that sets MANPATH and exports.  Just comment this block out.  Modern manpages compute path dynamically.

The offending lines are:

```
#  if [[ -z "${MANPATH:-}" ]]
#  then
#    export MANPATH="${rvm_man_path}"
#
#  elif ! [[ ":${MANPATH}:" =~ ":${rvm_man_path}:" ]]
#  then
#    export MANPATH="${MANPATH}:${rvm_man_path}"
#  fi
```

Comment: There is actually a pull request for this issue :
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/966

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed already as @Ashely noted in comment, proper way is to update RVM: `rvm get head` and to open new terminal / relogin depending on the installation type.